# How to prevent a 'Array index out of range' error?

Tags: swift

Is there a way, similar to using `if let` and/or optionals, to test whether you are about to index an empty buffer in Swift?

Comment: I don't know what it means. That is an error I get when I try to access an array index that doesn't exist yet; too high. The array might have 10 elements, but the app tries to access the 11th.

Comment: So it's an array, check the bounds of an array using the count property (`array.count`)  GoZoner gives an example in his answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Define your own:

```
extension Array {
  func ref (i:Int) -> T? {
    return 0 <= i && i < count ? self[i] : nil
  }
}
```

The `ref()` function returns an optional, so it can be `nil`, and you can use the `if let` syntax to access the returned value from `ref()` when it exists.  You would use this as such:

```
var myA = [10,20,30]
if let val = myA.ref(index) {
  // Use 'val' if index is < 3
}
else {
  // Do this if the index is too high
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this very well. Can you show me how to use it and maybe what it is doing?

Comment: I think ref needs a better name. But I couldn't think one.